# Unexpected response data from HERE autosuggest endpoint

Tags: here-api

The response from HERE's /autosuggest endpoint has unexpected element in it.

When making a request to Here autosuggest endpoint like: `https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?at=51.73771300000001,19.454722&q=wlokniarzy 91&maxresults=10&language=sv&additionaldata=Country2,true&cs=pds&result_types=address,place&addressFilter=countryCode=POL`

In the response third element looks like:

```
{
        "title": "91",
        "highlightedTitle": "<b>91</b>",
        "vicinity": "92-432 Lodz",
        "highlightedVicinity": "92-432 Lodz",
        "position": [
            51.79221,
            19.42193
        ],
        "category": "900-9400-0401",
        "categoryTitle": "Street or Square",
        "bbox": [
            19.421049,
            51.791988,
            19.422041,
            51.792599
        ],
        "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
        "resultType": "address",
    }
```

Which I think should not show up looking like that.
It hard to even guess what this place suppose to be.
Is it a bug in Here autosuggest endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will take a look at the place, and the place should be removed from Place API.

Thank you for the report!